# Log "mEventCount = " @ HTC One M8

Tags: android, logging, android-sensors

I've tested my Android App with a Nexus 5 (4.4.4) and a HTC One M8 (4.4.4). 
But only with the HTC One I'm getting logs on log level info like this:

```
Application | TAG           | Text
<myapp>     | SensorManager | mEventCount = x
```

x is a increasing number.

I'm using the motion sensors in my app, but I don't like this counter in the logs. Do you guys have similar logs when you use the motion sensors with an HTC device?

Edit: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has come with Android 4.4.4.

EDIT2: Here are some code fragments:

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  this.sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
  this.accelerometer = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
  this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.accelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
  ...
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
      onAccelerationSensorChanged(event); break;
  ...
}

private void onAccelerationSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  // save to Manager
  this.manager.setAcceleration(event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
  // set some TextViews
  ...
}
```

I think it's the proper way to use the Motion Sensors. And the log messages doesn't appear at the Nexus 5. So I think it's a custom modification by HTC.

Comment: You mean it's not you manually logging this but Android doing this by itself?

Comment: Can you show code? How do you use the sensor?

Comment: @shkschneider that's right, the android os is logging under my application context.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure it's your manufacturer/carrier's ROM (modifications) indeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've updated the HTC to Android 5.0, this log message is gone.